# The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string

Tags: epub, validation

The xml string is the same on all the pages (.xhtml files)
Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Does the error tell you exactly which file? The package.opf file is also an xml file, which may be missing the required quotation marks.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a question, or is this a piece of advice?

Comment: It is a question.  It does tell me the file.  /OEBPS/j83643-Flower-Fairy_-epubBody-26.xhtml(1,15): The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the whole message here.

Comment: @JanisFriesler if the below doesn't answer your question do you mind making an [edit] to your question so I make a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be an issue with the code after I tested it in a dummy ePub with ePubcheck 3.0.  Since you haven't mentioned how the ePub was created I would trouble shoot by:

- Creating a new XHTML file and re-doing the contents of the old XHTML file in it to make sure there isn't any issues with the file or if the file is corrupted.
- Check to make sure your closing tag is proper or the document ends with `</html>`.  This can be tested by opening the XHTML file in a browser such as Chrome and you might get a code error in red at the top.
- Sometimes empty lines after `</html>` can cause a validation issue with ePubcheck so make sure to remove them.
- If this was created in an application like Sublime or BBEdit you can always validate the XHTML.